# Squash a group of commits with an intermediary commit within it

Tags: git, github

Let's say I have a project with a RELEASE branch which is used to exchange code between a group of programmers. Me and my colleague want to add new functionalities to the project so we create our own work branches from the RELEASE branch. I make 3 commits on my branch:

```
MYDEVBRANCH
---dev-commit-1---dev-commit-2---dev-commit-3
```

I want to merge this changes into the RELEASE branch but my colleague finished his code earlier and merged his branch into RELEASE before me so after I merge the changes the RELEASE branch looks like this:

```
RELEASE
---dev-commit-1---colleagues-commit---dev-commit-2---dev-commit-3
```

Is there any way to squash my dev commits into one commit without touching the intermediary commit ? All in all I would like to have something like this:

```
RELEASE
---colleagues-commit---my-squshed-commit
```

I know that I could squash commits before the merge but I wonder how to solve the specific problem I described above.

Comment: just to check: can you run `git log` with `--graph` option to see how branches are related ? For example: `git log --oneline --graph RELEASE`

Comment: I think what you are looking for is an interactive rebase. It lets you rearrange the sequence of the commits, and lets you squash commits together. Should be something like `git rebase <commit-before-dev-commit-1> -i` (maybe also a force). This is all assuming you are allowed to rebase the release branch.

Comment: If you _merge_, the history cannot be a flat history as you have shown. If your changes are in your own branch, then your colleague merging into `release` does not and cannot affect your own (unmerged) history.